# Can I say "thank you always"?

Tags: expressions

> Thank you always

Is this correct to say at the end of an inquiry to a customer service of my bank? 
What I want to say is I am thankful for not only this time but also for when ever I needed a help in the past including this time.

Comment: *Thank you always* Doesn't sound very good, using *As always, thank you* would be the best alternative. But most (if not all) of the time, just saying *Thank you* or *Thank you so much* is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following:

> As always, thank you.

Comment: To me, this sounds like you're really fed up with this customer, like you're saying *'And, just like the last twenty times you came here, thank you.'*. Wouldn't **'Thank you, anytime!'** be a better alternative?

Comment: OP was the customer.